# Hard Menu Button does not trigger the onKeyDown of AppCompatActivity after upgrading to api v26.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

After I upgraded my targetSdk to latest from `v25.3.1` to `v26.1.0` on Android Studio. I no longer get the `onKeyDown()` get called. I have the Log inside the `onKeyDown()` method that is not triggered. Except for menu button the log is printed for all other buttons like volume and back and also their corresponding functions are executed. The back-light turns on upon pressing the menu button and I confirmed that the menu button itself is fine. I tried it on different devices. 
I found that such a bug was once found in `v22` and which was later fixed by the google. I found a solution proposed by Mattia Maestrini which didn't work for me. I suppose the problem could be the same. Any suggestions or help. Thanks.

Update: Seems like no one has an answer for now. But if this is an update bug I guess others should have this question too. Till then I am transferring my code from `onKeyDown()` to `dispatchKeyEvent()` which works equally.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue myself and think I found out why it was happening.  There is a special case for the menu key in the super.dispatchKeyEvent() method.  If you [check the source](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3240) of Activity.java, you'll see it consumes the keypress under this condition:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU &&
        mActionBar != null && mActionBar.onMenuKeyEvent(event)) {
        return true;
}
```

Basically, if you press the menu key, have an actionBar, and the actionBar's onMenuKeyEvent() consumes the event, dispatchKeyEvent() will also consume the event.  When the event is consumed, it won't pass the event along to onKeyDown()

The solution for my problem was to just remove my action bar and replace it with a toolbar (my action bar wasn't doing much anyway).  After I did that, I was able to receive onKeyDown() in my app.